# How can i add these statements in app.json?

Tags: expo, react-native

I want to allow HTTP traffic in my app using the expo-managed workflow. What is the way to add these statements to the app.json file?

```
<manifest ...>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
  ...>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" ...>
      ...
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Expo apps will allow HTTP traffic by default you don't need to include anything. You can simply use `fetch` in your app and it will work without adding any permissions.

Comment: @IsaacCWay No, it doesn't allow. I had to add ngrok and use the HTTPS endpoint, then it worked.

Comment: Weird, maybe it has to do with you using HTTP instead of HTTPS. I've never had to do that in my Apps that I've deployed to Android, but I always used HTTPS and tested against a live server. Sorry about that.

Comment: @IsaacCWay In android, the expo allows HTTP requests. I was forgetting to add the port number in my HTTP requests. Sorry about that.

Comment: did you get this solved? i am having the same issue and cannot change the android manifest in expo and also using http and not https

Comment: @CarlosCraig as mentioned by ICW, expo apps allow http traffic. In my case, i forgot to add the port number in requests being made.

Comment: I've posted an answer in other post, that may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/74212288/8139569](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74212288/8139569)