# How to add values to app.json for android in expo managed workflow?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I need to add those to Android files:

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

But I'm using managed workflow and I don't know how to add those lines to `app.json` file.

Comment: any updates on this bug?

Answer (score 3):

I did this plugin which seems to work:

```
const { createRunOncePlugin, withAndroidManifest } = require('@expo/config-plugins');

const withAndroidManifestHavingBetterSecuritySettings = config => {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, config => {
    const androidManifest = config.modResults.manifest;
    const mainApplication = androidManifest.application[0];
    if(process.env.CHANNEL !== 'dev') {
    androidManifest.$ = {
      ...androidManifest.$,
      'xmlns:tools': 'http://schemas.android.com/tools',
    };
    mainApplication.$['tools:replace'] = 'android:usesCleartextTraffic';
    mainApplication.$['android:usesCleartextTraffic'] = 'false';
  }

    return config;
  });
};

module.exports = createRunOncePlugin(
  withAndroidManifestHavingBetterSecuritySettings,
  'withAndroidManifestHavingBetterSecuritySettings',
  '1.0.0'
);
```

I had many issues related to merging of AndroidManifest files when `"developmentClient": true` in my `eas.json` file (related to me `dev` eas profile). I believe that it's related to the fact that the debug/AndroidManifest is a higher priority manifest than main/AndroidManifest (not sure though). So my solution was not to ignore the changes when building the `dev` profile. Hardening security settings in development builds do not seem useful anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

So I struggled with this problem for a while now and the only solution I could come up with was setting the minimum sdk version of the android app from 21 to 28. This is not ideal as my application now does not support old android devices, but doing this defaults the usesClearTextTraffic flag to false.

Answer (score 0):

If your app works fine while developing in expo, but after generating the APK some functions don't work, try this. In my case the **APK** crashed on login, but building in development with expo was working fine. The problem was that traffic is encrypted so that's why I ended up here trying to set clear text traffic. The problem in my case was with expoPushToken, in the APK it throws an exception I wasn't catching (building with expo worked fine as I said before, no exception). So, if the exception happens just catch it and set the token to empty string.
So, I had this:

```
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";

export async function getDevicePushTokenForAPP() {
        const pushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
        return pushToken.data;
    }
```

So then, I added the try and catch:

```
export async function getDevicePushTokenForAPP() {
  try {
    const pushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
    return pushToken.data;
  } catch (e) {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Now if you build the APK again (expo build:android) it should work fine, in my case login worked. But please note this is for testing purposes only, I needed the APK to quickly show it to the client. (Note that you will need the bundle, not the apk, when uploading to the Playstore). This is a quick fix for you to test the APK; but with no token, push notifications won't work. The final fix is to add firebase to your project, it's mandatory now, so add firebase and with the firebase unique ID, your push notification will work in your APK.
My conclusion is that expo uses its own ID to communicate with firebase, that's why it works while developing but the APK doesn't go through expo and tries to connect to firebase directly, but crashes because there's no ID.

Answer (score -2):

You should update your `app.json` like that:

```
"android": {
      "usesCleartextTraffic": true,
       uses-permission android:name
    },
```

Comment: When I add the text "usersCleartextTraffic":false in app.json it gives me an error

Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configur
 • Field: android - should NOT have additional property 'usesCleartextTraffic'.